# send commands to serial port using putty and .bat file

Tags: batch-file, putty, plink

I would like to send following AT commands automatically by creating a .bat file using PuTTy.

AT

ok

AT+CPIN = 1234

ok

I can do it manually so far. But I would like to do it automatically by executing the above commands by just clicking on a batch file. Can someone please help me with the commands to prepare my .bat file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hey, downvoter, this is a goodish question, while not the best, there is no reason on the face of this earth for you to downvote it without commenting. (or to down vote it period..... IMHO)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

commands.bat:

```
@echo off
echo AT
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
echo AT+CPIN = 1234
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul 2>&1
pause >nul 2>&1
```

send.bat:

```
commands.bat | putty -load test
```

where send.bat and commands.bat are in the same directory, and you execute send.bat

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. AT commands are used to connect to modem via a COM port to make a call or send sms. 
So far in putty, I have saved a session called 'test' with COM5 and speed 9600 and created a batch file with following command in send.bat:
plink -load test
pause

Comment: I have saved a session called 'test' with COM5 and speed 9600 and created a batch file with following command in send.bat: 


plink -load test 

pause

After each command, I need to press enter to get response 'ok' from the modem.

Example: AT <enter>
AT+CPIN = 1234 <enter> 

How can I accompilish this using .bat file?

Comment: see, the newline is automatically sent if its in commands.txt, just put EXACTLY what you would type into commands.txt, and the pipe will (hopefully) cause plink to think you are typing the contents of commands.txt.

Comment: ohk..after wrtiting the above commands in commands.txt, now my send.bat file will look like this: 

echo off 

plink -load test 

type commands.txt 

pause

am I right nephi12?

Comment: no, it will look like the send.bat im updating in my answer right now.

Comment: ok nephi, got it. And do we also have some command to wait for getting the OK response from modem? Or is it done automatically after plink 'READS' enter in the commands.txt?

Comment: well, it *should* be done automatically... but... here is the thing. plink is gonna take the input from commands.txt as fast as it can, so it *might* send the second command too soon... it really depends on whether plink will take input while the modem is sending back ok... you *should* be fine though, and if you arent, we can try another solution that im cooking up, but i dont know if it will work or not. try what we have now if you can, and get back to me with the results, btw, i have to go in .... about 2ish hours.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I cannot try it _now_ as I do not have the modem at my place. However, I _may_ try it tomorrow. In any case, I will get back to you with the results as soon as I try it, @nephi. :-)

Comment: alright, ill be on tomorrow between approx 2 hrs ago, and 4 hours after that (timezones are weird) so aim for that time slot

Comment: Hi nephi, sorry for the late reply. Was busy working on other projects.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have tried your solution. I have 4 commands, which I have typed in a .txt file. And 'READ' then using the batch file. First command is entered fine and I also get a reply OK. But then, the next command is skipped and the third command is 'READ' onto the cmd prompt. I think it is reading too fast. Ideally, we should wait (sleep for about 0.5s)before reading the next command from the txt file. 
What do u suggest?

Comment: use `timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul 2>&1` to pause for one second.

Comment: this line should be inserted in the .txt file after each of my  command..Am I right?

Comment: I think, we should pause for 1s after 'READING' enter and before 'READING' the next command from the txt file.

Comment: I have inserted the pause line (timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul 2>&1) for 2seconds in the .txt file as u suggested. It reads fine till the pause line. And then it simply stops there and does not proceed further i.e. the remaining lines are not read from the txt file.